# Rundeck works fime on script but nothing happen on remote server

Tags: remote-server, rundeck

I'm newbie on rundeck , and i design a job to execute script on remote machine. In UI i get the correct log and everything is fine and shows the service PID , but nothing happen and there is no proccess with that pid on remote host.
Does Anybody has same experience?

I am working on activemq to running on remote host.

Comment: Make sure that the job is dispatching to the remote node. Take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#creating-a-job (also, you can test your remote nodes using the commands section: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/06-commands.html#commands)

Comment: yes, i do but the result is the same.

Comment: Please follow this quick guide to set up remote nodes and execute jobs on them: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6022#issuecomment-624678947

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the job is dispatching to the remote node, follow these steps to configure and test it:

1. Go to the remote SSH node (using the account that you want to connect from Rundeck), add the Rundeck server user public key to the `authorized_keys` file.
2. On the Rundeck side, add to key store the Rundeck server user private key (remember to include the first and the last line "`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`" and "`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`").
3. Create a new Project and then create the `resources.xml` file with remote node information. To generate that file just go to Project Settings > Edit Nodes > Click on "Configure Nodes" button > Click on "Add Sources +" > Select "+ File" option > in "Format" field select resourcexml and fill the path in "File Path" field (put the file name at the end, usually "resources.xml", also, select "Generate", "Include Server Node" and "Writeable" checkboxes and click on the "Save" button.

Now you can edit that file including the remote node, in my case is "node00" (a Vagrant test image),  on `key-storage-path` attribute i used the same path created in the step 2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <node name="hyperion" description="Rundeck server node" tags="" hostname="hyperion" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.15.0-66-generic" username="ruser"/>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

4. On Rundeck GUI go to the sidebar and check your nodes on the "Nodes" section.
5. Go to "Commands" (sidebar) and put the SSH remote node name as a filter and launch any command against the remote node.